# In Wordpress, Getting The Site URL Inside a Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, wordpress, background-image, media-queries

I'm doing a responsive theme for a site. I need to be able to change a div's background image when the window size is smaller than 420px.

I needed to be able to reference the site url in order to set the background image in the first place, so originally I used a PHP tag and inline styling like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/home.jpg'; ?>');"></div>
```

But I need to change that background image when the window gets smaller.

All the other responsive css is going in this media query, inside style.css:

```
@media (max-width: 420px){
    div {

    }
}
```

Here's my plan. I could either do use style tags on the .php page to use that same php snippet to get the url, and hence the image. But, that style tag doesn't seem to take any affect...

```
<style>
  @media (max-width: 420px){
    .home-background {
      background-image: url('<?php echo bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/home_page/bg-mobile.jpg'; ?>');
    }
  }
</style>
```

Or, I could use javascript, but I want to try and avoid that, as it seems hacky to me...

How can I reference the site URL inside my style.css so I can change the background image on the fly

Comment: You could just copy the URL that's output by the PHP and paste it into the CSS file?

Comment: Can't you use relative paths for your URLs ?  with / as the root path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_head](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) action hook to echo your style in `<head>` tag. You should set your rule `!important` because you need to override default one.
Using this hook grant you to conditionally set if your rule will be or not printed in your  tag

In your functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'so18685496_print_my_style' );
function so18685496_print_my_style(){
    //we are on homepage? this is an example you can strip the if statement
    if( is_home() ){ ?>
    <style>
        @media (max-width: 420px){
          .home-background {
            background-image: url("<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/home_page/bg-mobile.jpg")!important;
          }
        }
    </style>

    <?php }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the slash in front

```
<style>
  @media (max-width: 420px){
    .home-background {
      background-image: url('images/home_page/bg-mobile.jpg');
    }
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this also inside the default style.css. It will work.

```
@media (max-width: 420px){
.home-background {
      background-image: url('images/home_page/bg-mobile.jpg');
    }
}
```

If it doesn't add `!important`